# Meteor custom mongodb during development

Tags: mongodb, meteor

How would I use a (live running) MongoDB to develop another meteor app? I tried modifying (`.meteor/server/server.js`) and specifying `MONGO_URL` to no avail before running `meteor`.

This is without using the bundled MongoDB, it has to be a separate/custom one (basically of another meteor instance).

This can be done with the [deploy method](http://docs.meteor.com/#deploying) but what about the normal `meteor run` during development?

UPDATE: this does work however the client side implementation seems a bit glitchy

Comment: I got the same question, but cannot find the answer here. Actually I didn't find ./meteor/server folder, but server.js in ./meteor/local/build/server/ will always be rebuild when you restart meteor server.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Unofficial Meteor FAQ](https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq#user-content-how-do-i-hook-into-an-existing-running-mongodb-instance), you can invoke Meteor with the `MONGO_URL` environment variable set to the desired instance:

```
MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017 meteor
```

If your MongoDB handles multiple databases, you can indicate which one to use by appending it to the URL:

```
MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb meteor
```

You can even prevent Meteor from starting a local Mongo instance in development by running:

```
MONGO_URL=none meteor
```

Comment: Is there a way to store the variable somewhere in the project? Always typing `MONGO_URL=...` to spin up meteor seems stupid. Would be nice if it could be picked up somehow while just using `meteor run`. (I know, first world problems..)

Comment: @archiehicox No need. Just put that env-variable to your `~/.profile` file for user-wide propagation, or inside `/etc/environment` for system-wide propagation.

Comment: @Shehi That's a good way. You're right, it's not project-specific.

Answer (score 10):

I found that you should not forget to specify the database to connect to. In my case, I wanted a second Meteor instance to connect to the development MongoDB server from a first instance.

Meteor uses the HTTP port +2 for a development MongoDB, and database 'meteor', so the correct way to start the second server is:

```
MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:3002/meteor meteor --port=3800
```

Comment: It's actually HTTP port +1 (at least now it is). You can verify this by doing a `meteor mongo` call to connect to the default database. So the default database `mongodb://localhost:3001/meteor`