# Where can I find MongoDB documents created inside Meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

New to Meteor and MongoDB here. I have mongoDB running as a service in my server, and from what I understand, [Meteor installs it's own mongoDB in the `.meteor` directory by default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14373526/2317532), unless you [specify otherwise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12919526/2317532). I [know](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7247474/2317532) native MongoDB stores its data in `data/db` folder, but **where are the documents located for MongoDB as part of Meteor?**

I have found that the mongoDB binary is found (for me) at

`~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.ftql1v++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/mongodb/bin/mongod`

But scooping around that area didn't lead me to any documents, nor could I find any `mongodb.conf`, `collection.0`, `collection.ns` files. And there's no directory like `.meteor/local/db` as some answers suggested.

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15363710/2317532), however, I'm looking for the location on disk of the database documents, rather than the location of the address to access the database.

### Question

**Where are the documents located for MongoDB as part of Meteor?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are saved in your project directory at .meteor/local/db.

Comment: Oh! I was looking at the base `.meteor` directory (the one on my home directory). Thank you!